# Importance of Sobolev Spaces

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

Why Sobolev spaces are so important in study of partial differential equations? What could have light up the mind of researchers to use these spaces to analyze PDEs?

Comment: Because they have very nice and convenient properties and this allows, e.g., for very general solution results. The Poisson problem with right-hand side in $L^2(\Omega)$ always has a solution in $H_0^1(\Omega)$.

Comment: You can check a very nice answer here : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1327750/significance-of-sobolev-spaces-for-numerical-analysis-pdes